# Navigation on turtlebot3

Tags: ros, navigation, simulation, turtlebot3, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I would like to ask for help on navigation stack because I don't really understand how it works and how to use it.
I have a turtlebot, a map (pgm and yaml file) and a python script I made that handles various data.
In the script I need to start the navigation by setting the initial pose and the goal.... how can I do that?
(the equivalent of the buttons "2d pose estimate" and "2d nav goal" in rviz when you launch turtlebot3_navigation.launch).
Besides setting the poses, how do I start the navigation stack? I've followed the official turtlebot tutorial but honestly I didn't understand much about how the various launch files work.
Can anyone help me/explain how to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393878/navigation-on-turtlebot3/) by [Misrek](https://answers.ros.org/users/92782/misrek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-01-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The equivalent code for initial pose estimate is [there](https://answers.ros.org/question/114631/robot-estimated-pose/) (ROS Answers), sending goal poses could be find [there](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zjb_2krr1Xg) (YT video).

The best way to learn Navigation stack seems to be reading a lot of code on the GitHub - from official repositories and from example projects/demos (next to reading documentation, of course).

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Misrek](https://answers.ros.org/users/92782/misrek/) on 2022-01-07**:
Thanks for the reply.
I just read the links to set the initial pose estimate and I wrote a publisher who writes on the topic /initialpose....
but if I do rostopic echo /initialpose nothing is published.....

```
pub = rospy.Publisher('initialpose', PoseWithCovarianceStamped, queue_size=10)
initpose = PoseWithCovarianceStamped()
initpose.header.stamp = rospy.get_rostime()
initpose.header.frame_id = "map"
initpose.pose.pose.position.x = x
initpose.pose.pose.position.y = y
quaternion = get_quaternion(theta)
initpose.pose.pose.orientation.w = quaternion[0]
initpose.pose.pose.orientation.x = quaternion[1]
initpose.pose.pose.orientation.y = quaternion[2]
initpose.pose.pose.orientation.z = quaternion[3]
pub.publish(init_pose)
```

**Comment by [Misrek](https://answers.ros.org/users/92782/misrek/) on 2022-01-08**:
I solved it, it was enough to insert a sleep after the Publisher statement

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-08**:
@Misrek please accept @ljaniec answer if led you to the solution. You can accept by clicking on the check mark. Thank you